# Filtering out URI in Google Analytics not working

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics to track pageviews on my website. However, there's a specific URL that I want to ignore (www.example.com/android_api).

So, inside filters, I have this filter:
Custom Filter-> Exclude-> Request URI-> ^/android_api-> Not Case Sensitive

However, "/android_api" is still showing up in "Top Pages".

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Filtering doesn't work with the real-time portion of the analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain your viewing your reports after you've created the filter? There could be some lingering data occurring in your top pages if your time span is set to encompass the data prior to the filter.